# Ruby on rails + Braintree -> submit button not starting the create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, braintree, braintree-rails

I've implemented Braintree gem (with this help: http://www.sitepoint.com/integrate-braintree-payments-rails/).

In my view I have the "dropin" code:

```
  <div class="form-container radius-box glassy-bg small-10 small-centered medium-8 large-6 columns">
      <%= form_tag transactions_path do%>
        <p>Please enter your payment details:</p>
        <div id="dropin"></div>

      <%end%>
  </div>
```

When I remove it, object is being saved. But with this code, the submit button does not do anything. It's very hard to debug - there are no outputs at all ("create" action is not being started).

Comment: You have also added the necessary javascript to get the drop in to work correct?

Comment: Yes I did. And the drop is working. Problem is with the button.

Comment: Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. Would you be able to update your post with the full code of the view you're having trouble with? Make sure to include the loading of the Braintree javascript as well. Alternatively, you can reach out directly to [Braintree support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) for some one-on-one help with this.

Answer (score 1):

you need to have a submit button for any form to work.

Add this on your form.

```
<button type="submit" name="action">Submit Form</button>
```